# Macros Retains Static Values

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is a Macro which i use to select the IP. An alertview is popped up user tries to login based on that the respective IP is set to fetch the data from the Server.

```
static NSString *updateProfileDetails_URL=@"http://%@/api/Home/editProfile/ios/1";


#define getServerURl(url,selectdServer)[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%@"
withString:([selectdServer isEqualToString:@"live"] ?@"live_ip/folder_name":@"demo_ip/folder_name" )]
```

1. I selected the 'demo_ip' option login.
2. Logged out.
3. Selected 'live' option now.
   Problem here is that the demo_ip is called at certain places. Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
#define USE_TEST_URL 1   // use 1 for test and 0 for live

#if USE_TEST_URL  // define test urls here

#define API_URL @"http://...<TEST URL>"

#else  // define live urls here

#define API_URL @"http://... <LIVE URL>"

#endif
```

and

```
NSString *url =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",API_URL] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is none of the issue with Macro, There might've been a problem with your passing parameters, when you calling getServerURl(...)

When you need live, Make sure you passing 'live' in second parameter of getServerURl(...)! Because you are conditionally comparing 'live' lowercase value.

For more information: Macros are replaced by the preprocessor by their value before your source file even compiles. So There is no way you'd be able to change the value of the macro at runtime.

[image]